# Does Hibernate optimize several lazy one-to-one relationships to same child?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Entity `A` has two unidirectional & lazy one-to-one relationships to `B` (i.e. there's no inverse relationship).

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "first_b_id")
private B firstB;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "second_b_id")
private B secondB;
```

Lazy-loading works fine. BUT if I invoke

```
myA.getSecondB()
```

the SQL log shows that Hibernate issues something like

```
select * from B where id in (value1, value2)
```

Hence, the relationships are treated lazily but they're all loaded at once.
What are the explanations and work-arounds for this?

Oh, why is that so relevant you may ask... Well, the `B` entities are LOBs. One is the 5+MB original, the other is a 200KB "preview". Of course I only want to load the original if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is probably that you enabled [batch fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-batch) for the class B (or for every entity using the `hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size` configuration property).

Comment: Oh, man...of course you're right. It should have clicked when I saw the in-query as they're usually an indicator for batch fetching. Thanks!